# How to access a java script variable in render partial url of Rails ERB file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have below piece of code in `results.js.erb` of Rails application where I need to render the partial URL dynamically using the string interpolation concept. I was unable to interpolate `selector` value dynamically in the render. Any help in resolving this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var selector =  = 'rc'  // possible values rc,mc.vc....
$("div.enroll-item div." + selector + "-item").empty().html('<%= j render "test/health_check/#{selector}_check", text_helper: text_helper  %>');
```

Comment: `var selector` defines javascript variable. the `selector` local variable you are referencing does not defined as per above snippet. Do you encounter any error?

Comment: @AmitPatel I want to use the Javascript variable in the render instead of the ruby variable. I tried it as #{selector} ruby local variable but it is showing a local variable not defined. Is there an another way of adding javascript variable dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can instead define a ruby variable to be used while the `results.js.erb` file is being rendered.

```
<% ruby_selector = 'rc' %>
var selector =  '<%= ruby_selector %>'
$("div.enroll-item div." + selector + "-item").empty().html('<%= j render "test/health_check/#{ruby_selector}_check", text_helper: text_helper  %>');
```